# how to display textarea next many inputs line in a bootstrap form?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a form that the textarea field is next to many inputs lines:

```
<form class="form-inline">
<table id="table_form">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="td_form">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="login" placeholder="login">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td_form">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="email" class="form-control"  id="Email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td_form">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="td_form">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<input type="text" class="form-control"  id="Address" placeholder="Address">
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div class="col-sm-4">
<textarea class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="comments" rows="3"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
```

But this code display the blocks one after the other and I want to display `login, email and address` on the same column and the `textarea` on another column.How to fix that?

Comment: what you actually want.? i am not getting you

Comment: I want to dispaly the login,email and address on the same colum (one after the other) but I'd like to put the textarea next to them not in the last row such it was displayed by the program.Is it clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code, it will solve your problem:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form" role="form">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="login">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Address" placeholder="Address">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="comments" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use tables for positioning elements on the page! This is [depricated](https://www.w3.org/WAI/PF/HTML/wiki/Table/layout_TABLE_deprecation). Use block-level elements instead. For example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="form" role="form">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="login">Login</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="login">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Email">Email</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Phone">Phone</label>
      <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="comments">Comments</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="comments" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

If you don't need labels, then use

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <form class="form" role="form">
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="login">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="Email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="Phone" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-4">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" placeholder="comments" rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </form>
```

See [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Your textarea is already to the right of the other input fields. If you want it to become as wide as possible, use the class `col-sm-8` for its container and give it `width: 100%`, like in my codepen :

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jmZZQY

(It won't work well in a snippet, since it uses bootstrap, so please look at the codepen, where bootstrap is included)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works fine for you

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form class="row">
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">


    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="login" placeholder="Login" name="login">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" name="email">
    </div>
    
     <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" name="phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address" name="address">
    </div>
    
</div>
<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4">
 <textarea rows="3" class="form-control"> 
  
 </textarea>
</div>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

please follow the bootstrap inline form that is the good method to clear this issue...
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send invitation</button>
</form>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please check it..